# How to run a continuous python service in Linux?

Tags: python, services

Recently I've created a service using python. It contains a `while True:` that does a service. Given that it is the first time that I offer something like a service and I charge the client I have some basic questions (sorry for it) for more experienced developers.

1. Screen. Currently to run my application I use screen. I ssh the server, go screen, `python service.py` detach and close ssh. Is it the best way to do it? What others do? When it is something regular I use `crontab`. But now it is a continuously running service.
2. Everything is inside a `try:` - `except:` so if something unexpected happens it sends me an email. Despite, if the screen is abruptly closed (not sure why this could happen) I won't receive an email, and I will sleep relaxed when my service is actually not working. Do people add extra alerts? like, giving a name to the process and add some checker that if the processes is not running, receive an email?
3. Should I encapsulate everything on a docker container? If it is only one application that does not need to be scaled? Is that a good approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered writing a systemd service?

Comment: @Fiximan That's another approach I could take. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot answer why exactly you were downvoted, but you could take a look at the reasons why people vote to close the question. 1) You have several question in one - it is better to focus on one issue only (also because of how others may find a solution to their problem). Like: "how to run a continuous python service?" 2) The docker part is a separate issue and hard to answer without knowing your use case -> therefore opinion-based, also because there are other methods to limit resources for a process. 3) We see nothing of your script - maybe it fails due to other reasons? (XY-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a Docker image and running it is one option as you have mentioned.

However, a more simple approach on *nix systems could be to use the supervisord to run the service. Not only `python`, I have run all sorts of `perl`, `shell` and `ruby` scripts under `supervisord`. I have even run Flask applications under `supervisord` without the need for dockerizing those simple web services.

Infact on few occassions, when I had to run multiple services in a docker container for legacy application migration I have used supervisord in the ENTRYPOINT, although that is not recommended and defeats the whole containerization and cloud native philosophy, but we have to do these things sometimes.

On Ubuntu you can install `supervisord` as

```
$ sudo apt install supervisor
```

and then enable the supervisord service as -

```
$ sudo systemctl enable supervisor
$ sudo systemctl start supervisor
```

A sample configuration file can be as below -

```
$ sudo vi /etc/supervisor/conf.d/service_name.conf
[program:service_name]
command=/usr/local/bin/python_script.py
directory=/home/app
user=app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/service_name.log
redirect_stderr = true
```

The autorestart in the config will make sure the service is restarted if it terminates for some reason. The autostart will make sure if you reboot the system this service will comeup on its on provided you have supervisord enabled to start at systemboot.

Once you have created the service, you can run it as-

```
$ sudo supervisorctl start service_name
```

and you can check the status when you want as -

```
$ sudo supervisorctl stop service_name
```

To stop the service you use -

```
$ sudo supervisorctl stop service_name
```

You can read more about this here - http://supervisord.org/

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks  lot.